# What are static tables & dynamic tables?

Tags: terminology

I heard the term "static table" when I'am learning about dirty reads in database.

Can anyone explain what is a "static table" and what is a "dynamic table"? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> Static tables are the master tables that are populated with some
>   canned data at the time of creation of the database in a typical
>   system setup. Rather they have a pre defined set of data populated in
>   them that hardly changes. There is no specific term like Static table
>   and Dynamic table, but all tables that are used for inserts, updates
>   and deletes with data getting modified can be termed as dynamic tables

Source: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/static-and-dynamic-table#post-663097